# Symbol not previously defined (TRISA)

Tags: assembly, pic

```
                    list P=16f54
#include <p16f54.inc>

; CONFIG
; __config 0xFFFB
 __CONFIG _OSC_RC & _WDT_OFF & _CP_OFF 
    
  org    1FFH
  GOTO    Start                   ; go to beginning of program
  org     0
   
Init     clrf    PORTA   ;reset ports  
  clrf     PORTB
  movlw    b'00000000'           ;set port-a I/O   
  movwf    TRISA
  movlw    b'00000000'          ;set port-b I/O
  movwf    TRISB
  retlw     0

Start
   call      Init
Main
   bsf       PORTA,  0
   GOTO      Main                          ; loop forever

    End
```

Comment: Please format the code. Be sure to include an actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Check the datasheet of your target device:

[PIC16F54 | Microchip Technology](https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/pic16f54)

According to this datasheet, PIC16F54 doesn't have TRIS registers in the register file.
Instead of general instructions like `MOVWF`, you should use the special `TRIS` instruction to set `TRIS` registers in PIC16F54.

```
  movlw    b'00000000'           ;set port-a I/O   
  ;movwf    TRISA
  tris     PORTA
  movlw    b'00000000'          ;set port-b I/O
  ;movwf    TRISB
  tris     PORTB
```